# Magento 2 - Custom Shipping Carrier and methods not showing in frontend

Tags: magento2

I am currently trying to create a new shipping carrier that will get its rates and methods through xml online. It seems that everything is working fine since i was able to debug that the method collectCarrierRates in module-shipping\Model\Shipping.php is actually appending all the methods and their rates but they are not showing in the checkout/cart page.

If i leave the zipcode empty i get the carrier title and under it stating "This shipping method is not available. Please specify the zip code." but if i add the zip code the carrier title disappears and no methods are shown.

I would really appreciate any info on how to further debug this problem. Since i am not able to follow where the rates are going after being generated by this function.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your entire code here what have you done so far with folder structure

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this, @roger?